# Printing permutations of a given string

Tags: c, strings, recursion, combinatorics

I want some feedback on the program I developed in C for printing the permutations of a given string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
bool isUnique(char x[], int y)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < (y-1); i++)
     for (j = i+1; j < y; j++)
       if (x[i] == x[j])
          return false;
   return true;
}
void perm(char a[], char b[], int x, int y)
{
   if ((y == x) && isUnique(b,x))
   {
     b[y] = '\0';
     printf("%s\n", b);
   }
   else
     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
     {
        b[y] = a[i];
        if (y < x)
          perm(a,b,x,y+1);
     }
}
int main()
{
   char a[] = {'1','2','3','4'}, b[] = {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
   perm(a,b,4,0);
   return 0;
}
```

Also, please tell me where I'm making blunders as far as conventions and good practice are concerned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Do not use single-character names for variables.  This will make your code harder to understand.  Give them names based on their significance to the program.
- Put your two arrays on separate lines for clarity:

  ```
  char a[] = {'1','2','3','4'};
  char b[] = {'\0','\0','\0','\0','\0'};
  ```
- Arguments to a function that aren't modified within the function should be `const`.

  This applies to `a[]` in `main()`:

  ```
  const char a[] = {'1','2','3','4'};
  ```
- Parameters that aren't modified within a function could be `const` in order to prevent any accidental modifications.

  This applies to all parameters in this program *except* for `b[]`.
- Since you declare your `for` loop counters inside the loop statement, and you're using `bool`s, then it appears you're using C99.

  Two things you should be doing here:

  1. Consistently declare your loop counters inside the statements.  You're doing it the pre-C99 way in `isUnique()`.
  2. Your code does not compile with the `bool`s.  To use them, you must include [`<stdbool.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4767923/c99-boolean-data-type).
- You're inconsistently declaring your loop counters inside and outside the `for` loop statements.  Since you initialize them inside in one instance, you must be using C99.  If so, then this should be consistent for each of these loops.
- In `perm()`, you should have curly braces for the `else`, just as you have them for the `if`.  Make sure to maintain such consistencies throughout your program.

  You should also do this for the `for` loops and `if`s in `isUnique()`.  It is especially important here as it helps with maintenance and will allow you to add additional lines if needed.
- Functions in C that have no parameters should have a `void` parameter:

  ```
  int main(void) {}
  ```
- The `return 0` at the end of `main()` is unneeded; the compiler will do this automatically.

With these changes, I've come up with the following code (also tested on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/sUTPxu)):

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

bool isUnique(const char x[], const int y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < (y-1); i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < y; j++)
        {
            if (x[i] == x[j])
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void perm(const char a[], char b[], const int x, const int y)
{
    if ((y == x) && isUnique(b, x))
    {
        b[y] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", b);
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        {
            b[y] = a[i];

            if (y < x)
            {
                perm(a, b, x, y+1);
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    const char a[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4' };
    char b[] = { '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0', '\0' };

    perm(a, b, 4, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

- There is no need to write like:

  ```
  char a[] = {'1','2','3','4'};
  ```

  You can change it to:

  ```
  char a[] = {"1234"};
  ```
- Single character variables makes code harder to understand, so use proper names for variables
- Use `{}` for `if`, `else`, and `for` statements, even they have a single statement inside
- Actually you can do it without using second array like:

```
// This function is used for swapping two characters (From the array)
void swapCharacters(char *swappingCharacter, char *swappingCharacter)
{
    char temp;
    temp               = *swappingCharacter;
    *swappingCharacter = *swappingCharacter;
    *swappingCharacter = temp;
}


// Calculated the permutation
void calculatePermutation(char *string, int startIndex, int endIndex)
{
   int counter;
   if (startIndex == endIndex)
   {
     printf("%s\n", string);
   }
   else
   {
       for (counter = startIndex; counter <= endIndex; counter++)
       {
          swapCharacters((string + startIndex), (string + counter));
          permute(string, startIndex + 1, endIndex);
          swapCharacters((string + startIndex), (string + counter));
       }
   }
}
```

And call it as:

```
calculatePermutation(a, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Note that `char a[] = {"1234"}` (or just `char a[] = "1234"`) is not quite the same as the original, as it adds a `\0` terminator.